# Android: ViewPager with more 100 fragments: how to set position at the middle directly?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a viewpager with more 100 fragments inside. Actually, it represents a diary, so:
- 50 first entries is from today to today-50 days
- 51 : today
- from 52 is the 50 next days

So, at the beginning, I would like to start directly on position 51 (today), and not to load the first fragments automatically and lost loading time.

This is my adapter:
Ps: Defines.SCHEDULE_CALENDAR_AREA = 100

```
public static class CalendarTimelineAdapter extends CacheFragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private DateTime mDateTime;
    private int mScrollY;
    private Map mPageReferenceMap = new HashMap();

    public CalendarTimelineAdapter(FragmentManager mgr) {
        super(mgr);
        mDateTime = new DateTime();
    }

    public void setScrollY(int scrollY) {
        mScrollY = scrollY;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (Defines.SCHEDULE_CALENDAR_AREA);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment createItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = new FRAGMENT();
        return fragment;
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
        return (Fragment)mPageReferenceMap.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        mPageReferenceMap.remove(position);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPageTitle(int position) {
        int dayNum = computeDifferenceDays(position);
        DateTime dt = mDateTime;
        if (dayNum == 0)
            return MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.day_today);
        else if (dayNum == -1)
            return MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.day_yesterday);
        else if (dayNum == 1)
            return MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.day_tomorrow);
        else if (dayNum < -1)
            dt = mDateTime.minusDays(Math.abs(dayNum));
        else if (dayNum > 1)
            dt = mDateTime.plusDays(Math.abs(dayNum));
        return DateTimeFormat.forPattern(
                MyApplication.getInstance().getString(R.string.format_tab_date)).print(dt);
    }

    private int computeDifferenceDays(int position) {
        return position - (Defines.SCHEDULE_CALENDAR_AREA/2);
    }

    private long convertToMillisDate(int position) {
        int dayNum = computeDifferenceDays(position);
        if (dayNum < 0)
            return mDateTime.minusDays(Math.abs(dayNum)).getMillis();
        else if (dayNum > 0)
            return mDateTime.plusDays(Math.abs(dayNum)).getMillis();
        else
            return mDateTime.getMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: `viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getAdapter().getCount()/2)` ? Call this line after you called `viewPager.setAdapter()`

Comment: You can update and store current item positions in SharedPreferences and set updated value in setCurrentItem(value);

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to start directly on position 51 (today)

Call `setCurrentItem(51)` on your `ViewPager`.

> not to load the first fragments automatically

You can try calling `setCurrentItem(51)` before calling `setAdapter()`. I think that used to crash `ViewPager`, but a scan of [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) suggests that it may work now.

Otherwise, you're looking at forking `ViewPager` or not using it at all.

> and lost loading time

If calling `setCurrentItem(51)` before `setAdapter()` does not work, give your fragments some additional smarts to recognize the initial load versus ongoing operations, and delay the work for loading data for low-position fragments for the initial load.